# MySQL server on Ubuntu server 18.04.1 LTS no more responding correctly

Tags: mysql

I've made an upgrade form 16.04 to 18.04.1 without apparently any problem (hosted on a 1&1 dedicated server)
This server is running different Joomla! based sites
Had to restart MySQL server and then no more any response form MySQL server

Have tried re-installation with :

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Without any luck (ie none of our sites are running now)
Tried to stop and start MySQL server : no problem

Tried re-configuration with :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

Got this message after re-configuration :

```
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.35, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Didn't help either... I'm not that familiar with MySQL server (have installed it many times, never had any problem... used it without any problem)
But now I'm lost !

has someone an idea what I should do ?
Should I give you more information, fell free to ask (please dive me the bash command to enter, I'm not that fluent in Bash ) ?

Forgot to say

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

has still all the databases (I cannot loose them !)

I have recent backups of all of my sites via Akeeba Backup (site and database included)

Thanks in advance for your help and advises,

Stéphane

PS : please forgive me my English as it is not my mother language, I am French

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the last 50 or so lines of the `/var/log/mysql/error.log`? This will explain why MySQL is not responding.

Comment: HI Matigo, I've uploaded the yesterday error file onto my Gdrive, here's the link : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ooBCACZ9NM3GT44tS2o55kM83ePYMDwf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No I have setup a user for the sites (Joomla! configuration has the user and pass for it)

Comment: Is the change of the mysql config without stopping it not the source of my problems ?

Comment: That's what I have done, I've restarted mysql with the changes made and no more any of my sites was showing. Then I marked out my changes # in front of them, restarted, nothing...

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I do not know what to do now to get rid off this error...

Comment: Looks like you have a password on your `root` account, which isn't surprising if you're coming from 16.04 or earlier. Use `sudo mysql -u root -p` instead, then enter the password when prompted.

Comment: Ok connected to mysql... and now, what should I do ?

Comment: If you can connect, that signals that the database may be fine, but Joomla is not. Check your Joomla logs for SQL errors. These may be in `/var/log/apache2` as one of the `*-error.log` files. With a specific SQL error, you can determine what the problem is.

Comment: With status I've got this :
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

    Connection id:          5347
    Current database:
    Current user:           root@localhost
    SSL:                    Not in use

| Wondering that SSL is not in use as I am using it on my sites ...

Comment: This is why I asked if Joomla was using `root`. Nothing is allowed to use `root` anymore. Joomla will need to be configured to use its own account, even if you grant that account full access to the database  (The SSL comment is probably "SSL to the database", which is unnecessary for your situation)

Comment: I've got a PHP error in all sites logs : PHP fatal error : Allowed memory sise of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 byte in ...

Comment: I normally charge clients $50/hr. for this sort of stuff ... . That said, you'll need to go into your `php.ini` file, find `memory_limit`, and increase it to something a little more realistic, like `256M`. This will be somewhere in a `/etc/php*/` directory, which depends completely on which version of PHP you have installed.

Comment: Matigo, Thank you so much ! You saved my day ! I really appreciate your help especially that normally you should charge for it ! All my sites are back ! Again Many thank for your kind help !

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your answer. Posting an answer (and when you can, accepting it) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I know where the problem come's from !

I've installed a Joomla! extention that requested some modifications in the Mysql configuration
So I've modified the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file with the following inputs :

```
interactive_timeout = 120
wait_timeout  = 120
connect_timeout = 120
```

and this without stopping MySQL !

I messed all up this way...
But now, how could I rebuild/rewind ?

Thanks for your help and advises
Stéphane